# How to take whole numbers from score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to take whole numbers from my score to add it to my "Coins" 
Example:
The idea is when player reach the end of game or when he dies his score gets exhanged for coins.
Idea is if i put
40 = 1 coin.
If he makes score 85 , we give him 2 coin. If he makes score 145 we give to him 3 Coins..
or if I define
50scores  = 1 Coin.
if he makes 245 score he get 4 Coins..

I tried to make same thing with my knowledge but the coins he get sometimes increase too much and player gets 4 not 2 coins.

This is my code that look for score and try to calculate how much to give player, but as i said it doesn't work.

```
int points = (GameManager.Instance.score / 40);

Debug.Log("POINTS ARE" + points);

if (points >= 1)
{
    gold = points;

    int goldl = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gold");
    goldl += gold;

    //Debug.Log("here is finished gold" + goldl);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("gold", goldl);
}
```

Comment: What is it that doesnt work?

Comment: Be **super specific** about what isn't working.

Comment: Where are you defining the type of `gold`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Mathf.FloorToInt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) to accomplish this

```
int score = 245;
int coins = Mathf.FloorToInt(score / 50);//will give 4
```